# Assigning model value to JavaScript variable MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to make a image slide show and I am passing urls of the images through a **List** in a **Model**.

```
List<string>
```

Onload I want to assign these URL values to JavaScript variables.

```
var image1=new Image()
var image2=new Image()
var image3=new Image()
```

My question is, how can I assign this list of URLs to the above variables, normally I can do this:

```
image1.src="value.jpg"
```

How can assign the value using `Razor` within JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

This razor code will create an image object with the index for each element in your List of strings and will set its src property.

```
<script>
    @for (var idx = 1; idx <= Model.ListOfImages.Length; ++ i) {
       <text>
           var image@(idx) = new Image();
           image@(idx).src = '@Model.ListOfImages[idx]';
       </text>
    }
</script>
```

Of course you will want to wrap it in the **script** tag. The output will be JavaScript that looks something like this:

```
<script>
   var image1 = new Image();
   image1 = 'image1.jpeg';
   var image2 = new Image();
   image2 = 'image1.jpeg';
   var image3 = new Image();
   image3 = 'image1.jpeg';
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening inside the for loop

Comment: Sure inside of the for loop you generate two javascript statements for each item in the list 1) defines an image objects 2) sets its src property to the value from the list. and <text> tag is a razor directive.

Comment: bravo.. will check it out

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways to solve this:

1. Use Razor to generate JavaScript

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var images = [], image;
   @foreach (var image in ListOfImages)
   {
       image = new Image();
       image.src = @image.url;
       images.push(image);
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Use Razor to generate HTML, then have JavaScript use the HTML for the slideshow

   ```
   <div class="slideshow">
       <ol>
       @foreach (var image in ListOfImages)
       {
           <li><img src="@image.url"></li>
       }
       </ol>
       <a href="#" class="slideshow-prev">Prev</a>
       <a href="#" class="slideshow-next">Next</a>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       // some imaginary jQuery plugin to create a slideshow
       $(".slideshow").slideshow();
   </script>
   ```

I'm partial to solution #2. I try to avoid having a server side templating language generate code in more than one language if at all possible. In solution #2, Razor is just generating HTML.